# r shiny - DataTableOutput - color specific rows and colomns

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

Is there a way to color specific rows in r shiny's dataTableOutput?

All I've found is that I can set orderClasses = TRUE to color ordered columns, but I'd like to always color column 2 and row 2 of the output data table. I've been reading through the options manual but haven't found anything.

-----------edit-------------

Ok, so after Yihui and user5029763's suggestions I'm now able to highlight columns using DT, but I'm still having trouble highlighting rows. Here is my code using the iris data set as an example - here I'm trying to highlight entire rows if the Species is setosa, however, on my computer, it's only highlighting the cells that say setosa:

```
datatable(iris) %>% formatStyle(
  'Species',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual('setosa', 'gray')
)
```

[image]

------- edit -----------------------

sorry for the long post - in fact, I ran the exact code as was specified here: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

```
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
  'V6',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```

And it is still highlighting just cells rather than rows on my computer. I'm using 3.2.1 version of R and Version 0.99.447 of RStudio. I also have the github version of shiny, not sure if that might override any options in datatable?

Comment: I believe this would require creating a custom `.css` file and making a new class (e.g. `.dt-hightlight { background-color: yellow; }`) and applying it to the relevant rows/columns. I'm not sure about row classes, but for the columns, there should be an option for `className`.

Comment: yes the annoying row...

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you have been reading, but please read this if you have not: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html

Comment: Ah, I was using shiny's renderDataTable functions, not DT, so I was looking at shiny's page - http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html, as well as the jQuery datatable page - http://datatables.net/ (which was linked to from shiny's page). The DT package seems to be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

The link Yihui posted explains formatStyle really well, but I think the argument 'target' is not mentioned there.

To color an entire row, use the argument `target="row"` in `formatStyle`.

Comment: Thank you, this is along the lines of what I'm looking for. Now I'm able to highlight columns, following Yihui's instructions, and ONLY ONE CELL rather than one row by using target = "row". I'm putting code up in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The option to use `target = 'row'` is only available in the developmental version of the `DT` package on github, not in the CRAN version.

To install the developmental version

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

Your code above should then work. @yihui can maybe confirm this?